# Why are there no builtin JS functions for cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Okay, this question might sound absurd, but why are there no implementation to modify cookies through JS. I ask this because over the web, I've seen some quite horrible implementations to manipulate cookies.

Also, why is cookie not represented as an Object? It seems to me if cookie was represented as an object, it would've been far far easier to manipulate it. Then document.cookie can just be a string representation of the object.

Comment: Ask browser vendors and specification editors. We don't know *why*, we just know how to write a workaround.

Comment: That's what my question is. Is there a specific reason to not have such functions?

Comment: Cookies by themselves don't have anything to do with JavaScript. They are part of the HTTP protocol (I guess), so I don't see why JavaScript, the language, should have anything to do with it. But I agree that browser vendors could provide better a better API.

Comment: I've wondered this myself, +1.

Comment: @dqhendricks I don't think a better API will reduce flexibility. You could still work with `document.cookie` string if you wanted "low-level" access.

Comment: @dqhendricks I'm not really sure if that is possible. However, that was just an idea. I'm sure better ideas are there.

Answer (score 1):

`document.cookie`, even if it sounds like a simple property, hides in fact function accesses (a getter and a setter).

Why isn't the cookie a whole structured object ? I guess the reasons are:

- the same than for localStorage : to force you set only very light data, in order to not make 
  the cookies heavy on disk
- standard usage both on server, client, and in-between (ie transmission)
- easy normalization process...

To answer to comments :

- I don't say it was right : I see some reasons
- I suppose the localStorage API is the logical successor, a little better (still not perfect)

Comment: But it's still a horrible stupid API.

Comment: There is absolutely no justification for the `document.cookie` API. It sucks, plain and simple.

Comment: The point of my comment is that there is no real reason for the API to be like it is.

Comment: Proposing complex (rich) local storage API isn't simple. Look at what happened to the web sql api (based on sqlite).

Comment: How is `get/set/delete` complex? There are many wrappers for `document.cookie` which give an API that `document.cookie` should have given in the first place, not this stringly typed weirdness. And they are not complex at all.

Answer (score 1):

`document.cookie` is the way it is because that's how it was first implemented. It's a crap reason, I know, but you have to remember the history of the early web. The first browser to implement a new feature set the standard for all other browsers to copy.

It's the exact same reason that `null == undefined` in JavaScript. Old bugs become required implementation details, and we'll be stuck with it forever, or until next week, depending on who's actively working on the w3 specifications.

> Why are there no implementation to modify cookies through JS?

Because it wouldn't be backwards compatible. Obviously we can't change the existing implementation, so we'd have to create a new one. In creating a new one we'd want to create one that can be reasonably replicated by existing JS code to back-fill old browsers, but if we've got to add a polyfill to get it working anyway, why bother even adding the new feature to the browser?

So, we're never gonna see a better cookie right?

**wrong**. Browsers *are* adding a new object implementation to store data locally, it's called `localStorage`, and it can be reasonably replicated by cookies where it needs to be. This also allows us to separate the local information from the server information (servers can set HTTP only on cookies for server-only cookies).

Comment: To reply to your backward compatibility argument, doesn't it apply to everything new being implemented including HTML5 and CSS3. If we started worrying about adding a polyfill, we wouldn't have any kind of new development.

Comment: Basically what I'm saying is that it's wasted development cycles to support a feature that already exists. If you really want a new cookie API, write up a proposal and send it to the w3 working group.